# FATAL: Module kvm_intel is in use

Tags: linux, module, debian

I am trying to remove a module, but it keeps on failing with:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r kvm_intel
FATAL: Module kvm_intel is in use.
```

while:

```
$ lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel             120858  4 
kvm                   296583  1 kvm_intel
```

How should I remove kvm_intel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posterity, I tried:

```
$ sudo rmmod -f kvm_intel
```

And suddenly my computer started beeping, and switched to a virtual screen full of kernel message.

After a reboot, I simply tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libvirt-bin
```

and **then**:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r kvm_intel
```

Answer (score 2):

You could start by finding out what is using kvm with `lsof`:

```
# sudo lsof | grep kvm
```

Relevant processes are often qemu instances so `pgrep -a qemu` may also come handy.

Then try to kill the processes you find after making sure you don't need them.